# Вопрос относительно связанных таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

Вообщем у меня появилась... скажем так "необычная задача" вообщем есть таблица магазин, и у этой таблице через таблицу связей подключаются услуги, но проблема в том, что у некоторых услуг должно быть количество, и честно говоря я бы его запихнул в таблицу связей, т.к это будет проще для меня, но правильно ли это, со стороны нормализации или всё же для количества придется создавать еще одну таблицу.
Привожу sql код из миграций для более подробного представления таблиц.
Таблица магазин:

```
$this->createTable('{{%shops}}', [
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'created_at' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . '(11) NOT NULL',
        'updated_at' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . '(11) NOT NULL',
        'address' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL COMMENT "Адрес магазина"',
        'tariff_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . ' NOT NULL COMMENT "Привязка к тарифу"',
        'user_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . ' NOT NULL COMMENT "Привязка к бренду"',
    ]);

$this->addForeignKey('shopsUserId', '{{%shops}}', 'user_id', '{{%user}}',
        'id', 'CASCADE');
$this->addForeignKey('shopsTariffId', '{{%shops}}', 'tariff_id', '{{%tariff}}',
        'id');
```

Таблица связей (как она сейчас):

```
$this->createTable('{{%shops_addition}}', [
        'shop_id' => $this->integer(),
        'addition_id' => $this->integer(),
        'PRIMARY KEY(shop_id, addition_id)',
    ]);

$this->createIndex(
        '{{%idx-shops_addition-shop_id}}',
        '{{%shops_addition}}',
        'shop_id'
    );

$this->addForeignKey(
        '{{%fk-shops_addition-shop_id}}',
        '{{%shops_addition}}',
        'shop_id',
        '{{%shops}}',
        'id',
        'CASCADE'
    );

$this->createIndex(
        '{{%idx-shops_addition-addition_id}}',
        '{{%shops_addition}}',
        'addition_id'
    );

$this->addForeignKey(
        '{{%fk-shops_addition-addition_id}}',
        '{{%shops_addition}}',
        'addition_id',
        '{{%addition}}',
        'id',
        'CASCADE'
    );
```

И сама таблица услуг:

```
$this->createTable('{{%addition}}', [
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'created_at' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . '(11) NOT NULL',
        'updated_at' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . '(11) NOT NULL',
        'name' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL COMMENT "Название"',
        'cost' => Schema::TYPE_DECIMAL . '(12,2) NOT NULL COMMENT "Стоимость"',
        'about' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' COMMENT "Описание"',
        'type' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . '(3) NOT NULL COMMENT "Тип"',
    ]);
```

Нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: Если количество относится к услуге, то хранить в таблице услуг.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Нет тут немного по другому, ну допустим есть 1 магазин, и у него услуга POS-терминал в количестве 2 шт. Так понятно будет?

Comment: Тогда для количества еще одну таблицу. Потому что скорее всего будет время начала/завершения услуги. Например две услуги, одна из них завершается раньше. Услуги же разные могут быть. Либо активация услуг. Тоже удобнее будет. Доступна услуга в количестве 5 шт, но активировали пока только 3 шт.